# Gulp: Compile sass files with "sass" (not "gulp-sass")

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I want to compile my typescript and scss files with gulp. Unfortunately, it seems that `gulp-sass` do not support sass' `@use` statement. So I tried to use the `sass` package (this is not the `gulp-sass` package). Now my issue is that it seems that I cannot use `sass` in combination with `gulp`.

This error is thrown:

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: Closure '_render'
```

Link (Sass):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

My setup:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulp_rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var gulp_sass = require('gulp-sass'); //  ---------> Should not be used
var gulp_autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var gulp_sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var gulp_ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var gulp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
var gulp_concat = require("gulp-concat");

var sass = require('sass');
var glob = require('glob');


const filePaths = {
    styleSrc: 'src/sass/utility.scss',
    styleDist: './dist/css/',
    styleWatch: 'src/sass/**/*.scss',
}

gulp.task('build-sass', () => {
    jsFiles.map(
        function (entry) {
            return gulp.src(filePaths.styleSrc)
                .pipe(sass.render(entry))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(filePaths.styleDist))
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Look at `gulp-dart-sass` https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass

Comment: This works. Thank you!